# AWS VPC CNI Addon: Unable to update cni config" err="no networks found in /etc/cni/net.d

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubelet, cni

My cluster was working fine before and no changes was made to it. But a few days ago I noticed that the newly scheduled nodes are all in `NotReady` state. Here is what I could find in the kubelet log:

```
4069 cni.go:240] "Unable to update cni config" err="no networks found in /etc/cni/net.d"
4069 kubelet.go:2398] "Container runtime network not ready" networkReady="NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized"
```

An `ls -la /etc/cni/net.d` shows an empty directory. And I found that VPC CNI ADD-ON in in `degraded` state so I tried upgrade and remove it then recreate it. But no matter what I do to upgrade/recreate it, the add-on is always stuck in `upgrading` or `creating` state forever until it times out and gives me `creation failed` status.

AMI used: 1.23.17-20230711
k8s version: 1.23
vpc cni version: 1.10.4

I don't think it's the version incompatibility because I have other clusters running on the exact same version of k8s and vpc.

Been stuck on this for days. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you make some progress with this issue ?

Experiencing a similar issue when updating, tried to remove it, add it again, now it's stuck on creating.... stuck on this for ~24 hours  now....